# RestController test fails with h2 database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4, h2

I am trying to run a test to my `RestController` in my `Spring boot` application with `h2` database.
Here is some code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class E2E_EconomicOperatorAPIControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test public void test_newEconomicOperator() {
     //staff
     }
}
```

But when I run it, i get this error:

```
2018-04-03 12:16:57.084  WARN 14332 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-196]
```

And here is my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

logging.level.org.gso.admin=DEBUG
logging.level.gso.gd.client=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web.client=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.org.thymeleaf=WARN
logging.level.root=WARN
```

Comment: Try updating your datasource url for example something like: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE it appears without the clause on exit close h2's database automatically shuts down

Comment: Yeah i saw that answer in another stackoverflow question , but in vain. Already added in my properties file

Comment: Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you shouldn't need to set any property for an embedded h2 database, as boot configures that for you (additionally, I think you should leave out the `MODE=Oracle` flag). Here's what I did:
Put the following dependendy in your `.pom`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the scope. This will load the dependency on your classpath during test (and nothing else). You should then make sure, that you have an application.properties file per environment, where you set the database wehnever you need a real one.

As an example from my app:

**application-dev.properties:** (note: I wanted a real db for dev, so i put in prostgres...)

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.database.driverClassname=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.100:5432/winecellar
spring.datasource.username=winecellar
spring.datasource.password=winecellar
```

**application-test.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.database.driverClassname=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

And I have a similar file for production settings (using postgres as well...)

Then, as long as you annotate it as you have done with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`, you should be fine.

Comment: I work with H2 in dev mode also locally so its scope in my pom is 'runtime' so it's available also for test scope (as per docs)

Comment: Should be ok. Just change the properties file accordingly

Comment: Yes everything already fixed and my project works already fine but this is the first time I tried to work with resttemplate. BTW, I'm not getting this error when testing my service